# Creating own distance api using postgres and own servey data

Tags: postgresql, api, distance

I am interested to create my own distance API to find out driving distance between two points on road. I don't want to use Google or graphhoper. Can some one suggest any PostgreSQL method or any open source project rather than grasshopper.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is [pgr_drivingDistance function](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/src/driving_distance/doc/pgr_drivingDistance.html#pgr-drivingdistance) of [pgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/) extension to the [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) RDBMS.